# Restore single database on RDS SQL Server

Tags: amazon-web-services

When I look at the backup history on a my RDS SQL Server, I can see daily full backups and transactional backups every 5 minutes. But when I try and restore the database with the SQL Server Management Studio, logged in as the master user, I get

> User does not have permissions to restore the database

So the question is, is it possible to restore a single database. Or are the transactional backups used when the whole instance is restored via the RDS console.

Comment: I would say that they are used for PIT recovery. The master user of SQL servers is pretty limited, you can't do all you would do in a local installation.